# Функции DataTable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

можно ли где-то узнать про дополнительные функции DataTable?
Меня интересует импорт таблицы в Excel и более сложный поиск (а то здесь просто поиск совпадения абсолютно по всем полям). А мне понадобится поиск_столбец_1+поиск_столбец_2 и т.д.

Comment: а что за DataTable? Вы думаете, в мире js и php есть всего одна библиотека для таблиц?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я использовал https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: В DataTable вы все поиски и т.п. сами настраивать можете и будет работать так, как накодите. Насчет экспорта (а не импорта..), почитайте [HTML5 export buttons](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html) - с коробки доступны, работают адекватно, проверено временем.